# How to allow Chrome media permissions by default?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm working on a project that uses the Speech API and the Webcam API, so while testing, I have to tell Chrome to 'Allow' every time I refresh the page (which I have to do every few minutes), and it looks like a sheer waste of time to me. Chrome also allows you to set a default option for Plugins, Popups, Location, Images, Scripts, but not Media?